# How Do I Resolve "A specified Include path is not valid"?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a parent-child relationship setup that is fairly basic.  The end result is that I want to be able to return the resulting tables as JSON through ASP.NET MVC WebAPI. I am using Entity Framework 5.0 beta 2.

I can demonstrate the error I'm running into with a simple example. Given the classes `Category` and `Product` with the corresponding data context:

```
public class Category
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public virtual IEnumerable<Product> Products { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    public virtual int CategoryId { get; set; }
}

public class ProductDataContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to run a query that includes the products I get the following error:

```
A specified Include path is not valid. The EntityType 'FooAndBar.Category' 
does not declare a navigation property with the name 'Products'.
```

The statement to fetch is pretty straightforward:

```
var everything = dc.Categories
            .Include(c => c.Products);
```

What is the correct way to setup the columns and/or the query so that the `Products` are included with the `Categories`?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Child collection properties must be declared as an`ICollection<T>`, not an`IEnumerable<T>`.

Also, you do not need to explicitly add a `CategoryId` field to the child class; EF will create that automatically in the database.

Comment: I have posted a related question here if you care to take a stab: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10038628/error-when-serializing-ef-code-first-5-0-data-in-webapi-controller  Thanks for your help otherwise!

Comment: Quick and accurate answer. Thx!